# Adobe Business Catalyst URL Handle

Tags: business-catalyst

I would like to know if there is a URL Handler for Adobe Business Catalyst.

I want to use a canonical tag for all my pages that will look like this

```
<link rel="canonical" href="{page.url}" />
```

So it will automatically grab the URL of the page instead of me going in and adding it to every page all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You have the liquid output:
You have the page address module:
https://docs.worldsecuresystems.com/reference/modules/pages/module_pageaddress.htm

{module_pageaddress} - renders the current URL in plain text, for example http://mysite3.businesscatalyst.com/shop/product1